# Baire one functions, closed intervals

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

I've been wondering if you could help me with the following problem.

There's an article on Baire one functions (number 2 on google search list) and there is one thing concerning Lemma 9 that I am not quite sure about.

What I mean by this is: is the sequence $c_k$ an arbitrary one? None of its properties are actually mentioned in the proof.

Here is the link: http://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2007/huh.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is no assumption on the sequence $\{c_k\}$: what this lemma proves is that any linear combination characteristic functions of disjoint $F_\sigma$ sets is Baire one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought. I just wanted to make sure. The author could have written that, though:)